# Establishing the connection to a Redshift cluster in a golang app, using ODBC via SSH tunnel (using the AWS Redshift ODBC Driver)

Tags: go, ssh, network-programming, odbc, amazon-redshift

**The Goal**

I need to query a Redshift cluster from my golang application. The cluster is not available for public, so I want to use SSH to access the said cluster via bastion host.

**Status Quo**

- I have an AWS Redshift cluster in a private VPC, with inbound rules to not allow any traffic from the internet, but tcp 22;
- There's a bastion (which can connect to the cluster), so fowarding a port and using [rsql](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/rsql-query-tool.html) works perfectly fine from the terminal;
- I use ODBC, and the official ODBC driver from AWS;
- In golang application, I use the following db implementation of the ODBC https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc;
- I can't use [Devart's Redshift ODBC driver](https://docs.devart.com/odbc/redshift/ssh.htm);
- I can't use JDBC;
- MacOS/Unix.

**The Problem**

The problem is pretty much trivial. When cluster is available for public and accessible from the internet, the alexbramain's library does it job. However, when the cluster is behind the wall, that's when problems kick in.

The code of the library is translated into C (system calls), I can't really debug it. While, with mysql, e.g., it's possible to register your custom dialer, it doesn't seem to be a case with ODBC.

Even when the tunnel is active, providing an ODBC DSN to the local host for some reason doesn't work. The `SQLRETURN` is always -1 (`api/zapi_unix.go`).

**The Question**

Did someone have such experience? How did you resolve a problem of accessing the cluster from the internet via a go app?

Thank you!